# What error of this SQL code?

Tags: database, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, oracle12c

I am trying to insert value  in the  table A and I want to check if value exist print 'value is exist' and if not create new table and add value to table B. I will try following code but it will give compile error

Comment: Can you give us the error pls?

Comment: @adimoise91 I added Error. I am using SQL_DEVERLOPER , oracle 12c , hr database.

Comment: I think that someone didn't liked my answer. First problem in your procedure is that IF statement didn't have the THEN clause and END IF clause. IF condition THEN statements ELSE statements END IF;

Comment: Don't remove content when editing your post. Currently this makes no sense since the answers refer to code you posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes. This is the second version :D Try this please.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_job ( job_id VARCHAR2, job_title VARCHAR2 )
IS
   var   VARCHAR2 ( 4000 );
BEGIN
   IF ( SELECT job_id
          FROM jobs
         WHERE job_id = job_id )
         IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'Value already Exits' );
   ELSE

         -- insert new job in jobs table---
         INSERT INTO jobs
              VALUES ( job_id,
                       job_title,
                       NULL,
                       NULL );

         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
            'CREATE TABLE ' || 'EMP_' || UPPER ( job_id ) || '( 
                  EMPLOYEE_ID   NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL,     
                  FIRST_NAME   VARCHAR2(20) ,
                  LAST_NAME     VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
                  SALARY     NUMBER(8,2),
                  DEPARTMENT_ID  NUMBER(4,0),
                  CONSTRAINT fk_e' || UPPER ( job_id ) || ' 
                          FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
                          REFERENCES EMPLOYEES(EMPLOYEE_ID)
              )';
    END IF;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'ERROR' );


END;
/
```

The new version :D And try to not user variables like VAR or tables with name like "table"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_job ( job_id VARCHAR2, job_title VARCHAR2 )
IS
   err_msg       VARCHAR2 ( 4000 );
   stmt          VARCHAR2 ( 4000 );
   flg_cnt_job   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT ( * )
     INTO flg_cnt_job
     FROM jobs
    WHERE job_id = job_id;

   IF ( flg_cnt_job > 0 )
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'Value already exits' );
   ELSE
      -- insert new job in jobs table---
      INSERT INTO jobs
           VALUES ( job_id,
                    job_title,
                    NULL,
                    NULL );
      COMMIT;

      stmt := 'CREATE TABLE EMP_' || UPPER ( job_id ) || ' (
                   employee_id     NUMBER ( 6, 0 ) NOT NULL,
                   first_name      VARCHAR2 ( 20 ),
                   last_name       VARCHAR2 ( 25 ) NOT NULL,
                   salary          NUMBER ( 8, 2 ),
                   department_id   NUMBER ( 4, 0 ),
                   CONSTRAINT fk_e' || UPPER ( job_id ) || '
                       FOREIGN KEY ( employee_id ) 
                       REFERENCES employees ( employee_id ))';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      err_msg := SQLERRM;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( err_msg );
END;
/
```

Comment: many thanks .but still error. { Error(5,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an alternat }

Comment: You are using begin in the else statement and you end the if sentence before the exception as far as i remember.

Comment: You can use BEGIN and END inside of an ELSE clause. In my case the exception appear just when the ELSE will return an error. I will edit my post to treat the error for the entire IF. :)

Comment: @adimoise91 as far as i remember you do not use the BEGIN statement inside en else.

Comment: @Nyranith If you want to isolate and use an EXCEPTION block inside an ELSE, you can user BEGIN and END. You can try. In PL/SQL you can user BEGIN and END inside everything to see the code better or to expand/hide some code.

Comment: @adimoise91 still error { Error(5,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an alternat

Comment: @Natasha Let me know if the latest version is ok for you.

Comment: @adimoise91 your code compile and execute well.but same issue , return all table data count always. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the if sentence in the PL/SQL. You do not use begin but rather THEN, and you end the if before it is finished. 
How does this look ? 
Some time since i used PL/SQL so bear with me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_job(job_id VARCHAR2,job_title VARCHAR2)
IS

var varchar2(4000);
job_exists number := 0; 

BEGIN 


    SELECT COUNT(job_id) INTO job_exists FROM jobs WHERE job_id = job_id; 

    IF job_exists != 0 THEN 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('All Ready Value IS Exits');
    ELSE 
       INSERT INTO jobs VALUES (job_id,job_title,null,null);

          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  
              'CREATE TABLE ' || 'EMP_' || UPPER(job_id) ||
              '( 
                  EMPLOYEE_ID   NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL,     
                  FIRST_NAME   VARCHAR2(20) ,
                  LAST_NAME     VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
                  SALARY     NUMBER(8,2),
                  DEPARTMENT_ID  NUMBER(4,0),
                  CONSTRAINT fk_e' || UPPER(job_id) || ' 
                          FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
                          REFERENCES EMPLOYEES(EMPLOYEE_ID)
              )';
    END IF; 

    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN others THEN 
            dbms_output.put_line('ERROR');
END add_job;
```

Btw to get a better error output i like using:

```
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error occurred'); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error code. ' || SQLCODE); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error message. ' || SQLERRM);
```

Comment: @Nyranih ,still eoor. { Error(6,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(6,8): PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only }

Comment: @Natasha true, you cannot use EXISTS since that can only be used inside a sql statement. Updated it now to use COUNT. how does it look ?

Comment: compile well, but in execute :(  error { PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error }

Comment: @Natasha think went a little fast here, used the job_id in the if instead of the job_exists variable. :)

Comment: compile well, and execute ,your querry , return all table raw count. :/ so , don't execute , below line.